# How to exclude a page from making an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an admin panel for a restaurant and i have a problem with orders logic.

I have an Orders table and an Orders_check table.The Orders table have columns like name,address,details,price etc. and the orders_check table have only one column that can be 1 or 0.When an order is placed, the integer goes from 0 to 1.

On the admin panel,in the Orders page i make an ajax call every 5 seconds, i verify if the integer(from orders_check) is 1.If it's true, i take from database the unseen orders and i add them to the table.

All good untill now but i have a lot more pages in admin panel like products,create product, create category etc. and i have to make an ajax call on header every 5 secs to see if it's any new order and pop up an alert message.

The problem is that, if i'm on the orders page, i will have 2 ajax calls that will do the same thing.One from the header and one from the orders page.

How can i tell the header's ajax call to not do it if i'm on the orders page?

Header's ajax:

```
    setInterval(checkNumberOfOrders, 5000);

function checkNumberOfOrders() {
    var controllerOrderCheck = 'http://localhost/restaurant/admin/order/checkNumberOfOrdersAjax';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: controllerOrderCheck,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (param) {
            if (param.done) {
                $('#numberOrders').text(' (' + param.number['number'] + ')');
            }
        }
    });
```

Orders Ajax:

```
setInterval(checkOrder, 5000);
function checkOrder() {
    var controllerOrderCheck = 'http://localhost/restaurant/admin/order/checkOrderActionAjax';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: controllerOrderCheck,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (param) {
            if (param.done) {
                for (var i = 0;i< param.orders.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    var lastRow = table.row.add({
                        "Id": param.orders[i]['id'],
                        "Client": param.orders[i]['name'] +' '+ param.orders[i]['secondName'],
                        "Adresa": param.orders[i]['address'],
                        "Data&Ora": param.orders[i]['date'],
                        "Reducere": param.orders[i]['disscount'] + "%",
                        "Pret": param.orders[i]['price'] + " lei"
                    }).draw().node();
                    $(lastRow).css("background-color","rgba(255, 179, 102)");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @IoanAndrei To not do it you can cancel your setInterval. `var interval = setInterval(function(){ }); clearInterval(interval);` I would recommend you not to do this at all. Use an event based model never use polling.

Answer (score 0):

set those Ajax calls in variables, check `if( typeof FirstAjaxCall === 'undefined')` then you can call second ajax call.

```js
var FirstAjaxCall = $.ajax( /* logic */ );

// order page

if (typeof FirstAjaxCall === 'undefined') { // this means that FirstAjaxCall not exist which means the first didn't happen
  // call ajax order
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what i need or maybe i don't understand how this should work